# Excel Macro issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, macros, microsoft-office-2013

I have a very detailed and formula heavy workbook template that I use daily. I originally created it in Excel 2010.

I have several macro buttons I created that save certain sheets as PDFs in the workbooks directory.

For some reason when I upgraded to 2013, the macros for PDF ONLY work, if I save 1 sheet as a PDF once manually, I did not write the macro myself, I modified a copy paste from somewhere.

Below is a sample of one of the macros:

```
Sub PDF_3P()


ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("CD 1", "CD 2", "CD 3")).Select

 pdfName = ActiveSheet.Name
    ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fileSaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        fileSaveName _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "File Saved " & " " & fileSaveName
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual problem and what have you tried to fix it so far?

Comment: the macro works, but only if i create a pdf using save as at least once. then the auto pdf macros work. (worked fine without doing that in 2010

Comment: Are you getting any Errors?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Office 2013

```
Option Explicit
Sub PDF_3P()
    Dim FileSaveName As String

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("CD 1", "CD 2", "CD 3")).Select

    FileSaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    If FileSaveName <> "False" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
             Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             FileName:= _
             FileSaveName, _
             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
             OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```